# Flutter Run Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] Requires newer sdk version #31 (current version is #30)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build

When I try `flutter run` the following error occurs:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Flutter\appname\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1847062534.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #7):    
Requires newer sdk version #31 (current version is #30)]
Error launching application on SM A127F.
```

Here is part of my build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.domain.appname"
        minSdkVersion 31
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Comment: DId you try deleting the build folder doing a clean build?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately still the same error

Comment: Seems like the phone you are trying to run on that could be with sdk 30. Try changing your config to sdk 30

Comment: Yes, that's it! I used a physical device (Samsung A12) which needs Sdk 30. Switching minSdkVersion to 30 worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is due to android SDK version mismatch between your app and the target device (i.e. real phone or emulator).

From your case it seems like your app is built with SDK version 31 and you are trying to run it on a device which supports version 30 resulting in the issue. TO fix this either downgrade the your app's SDK need to 30 or run it on a newer device that supports SDK 31.

Comment: I already figured it out. This was exactly the problem. Target Device was on SDK 30 while App was on SDK 31. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you fix it? Which setting/line in which file (manifest?)?